# Trouble with replacing a Cartesian equation with polar equation.

Tags: polar-coordinates

This is the last question on my assignment and I can't figure out how to solve it. Replace the Cartesian equation with an equivalent polar equation:
$$
\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{49}=1
$$

I know that $x^2+y^2=r^2$ but when I try to work this out...

$$
\frac{4y^2+49x^2}{196}=1
$$
$$
\frac{4(r\sin\theta)^2+49(r\cos\theta)^2}{196}=1
$$
$$
\frac{4r^2\sin^2\theta+49r^2\cos^2\theta}{196}=1
$$
$$
r^2(4\sin^2\theta+49\cos^2\theta)=196
$$
$$
r^2=\frac{196}{49\cos^2\theta+4\sin^2\theta}
$$
$$
r=\sqrt{\frac{196}{49\cos^2\theta+4\sin^2\theta}}
$$

But I know this is very wrong.

Comment: Turn's out you're very right though. Everything works out mathematically, and [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ga6ifsfi2v) gives them as the same.

Comment: A tip for future reference, use "\cos" and "\sin" for trig functions so that they appear like this:$\cos,\quad\sin$ rather than slanted like this $cos,\quad sin$

Comment: In addition to @mrnovice's advice also see [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are totally correct : You have done what *is* done to find polar form of any equation, i.e.

> Assume the polar coordinates of a curve to $\big(r(\theta)\cos \theta,r(\theta)\sin \theta \big)$ and put it into the cartesian equation of the curve, and then solve for $r(\theta)$.

For an ellipse  :

> $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

The polar coordinates of point $\text{P}$  are given by :

> $$\text{P} \equiv\Big(r(\theta)\cos \theta,r(\theta)\sin \theta\Big) ; ~\text{where}~r(\theta)=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2 \sin^2 \theta+b^2 \cos^2 \theta}} $$

You can confirm yourself [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center) on Wikipedia.

Comment: I believe there is a mistake in your answer: $r(\theta)=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2 \sin^2 \theta + b^2 \cos^2 \theta}}$

Comment: @Anon Thanks for correcting me, it was probably a typo.